# Kernel dying in Jupyter notebooks with metpy

Tags: jupyter-notebook, metpy

running any metpy function is fine till plotting when the kernel repeatedly dies. I think this may be a hardware issue but curious for answers

Comment: Does the kernel die if you plot using plain `matplotlib` without doing any `metpy` imports?

Comment: Also, it would be very helpful to see the full set of code executed before the kernel dies, as well as the version of MetPy and operating system you're running.

Comment: Will do, I’ll send it here later tonight

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.